# Cannot resolve method setText(java.lang.String)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've looked at other questions similar to the error I'm getting, but I can't seem to figure out the issue here. All I'm trying to do is click a button and change a TextView's text.

My code is as follows:

```
public class FindBeerActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_beer);
}
//call when the user clicks the button
public void onClickFindBeer(View view) {

    //Get a reference to the TextView
    View brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);

    //Get a reference to the Spinner
    Spinner color = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.color);

    //Get the selected item in the Spinner
    String beerType = String.valueOf(color.getSelectedItem());

    //Display the beers. This is where the error is
    brands.setText(beerType);

  }
}
```

and the XML

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/brands"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/find_beer"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/find_beer"
    android:layout_below="@id/find_beer"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/brands" />
```

When I build I get: "error: cannot find symbol method setText(String)

I'm following a tutorial to the letter and I can't see where I've made a mistake, so I'd appreciate it if you guys could help me out! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

You can either change

```
View brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
```

to

```
TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
```

**OR** change

```
brands.setText(beerType);
```

to

```
((TextView)brands).setText(beerType);
```

In either ways, you need to **call the `setText` method on a `TextView` reference**.

Comment: Yup, there's the mistake. I'm not sure why I created that as a View and not a TextView! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying setText() method on a view object. You need to call it on a TextView object.so either change the declaration of brands to TextView or just wrap ur brands object to TextView before calling setText() over it.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
View brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
```

To

```
TextView brands = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.brands);
```